# Java 9 Flow define subscriber with lambdas

Tags: java, rx-java, java-9, java-flow

I start playing with Java 9 Flow API, and the first thing that I found and dont like, it´s seems like we cannot use lambdas when we pass a subscriber implementation into the publisher as we can do with RxJava

So I have to define and implement my own Subscriber class

```
public class CustomSubscriber<T> implements Flow.Subscriber<T> {

        protected Flow.Subscription subscription;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
            this.subscription = subscription;
            System.out.println("Subscription done:");
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T item) {
            System.out.println("Got : " + item);
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
```

And then just pass it to my publisher

```
   SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();
    publisher.subscribe(new CustomSubscriber<>());
```

This is really verbose, and as I understand it´s because we need to set the  subscription in the `onSubscribe` callback

```
protected Flow.Subscription subscription;
```

To later be used in the `onNext` to continue the emissions `subscription.request(1);`

I still dont get it why this mechanism it´s needed, but it´s avoiding the use of Lambdas as we do in RxJava as this example

```
SubmissionPublisher<String> publisher = new SubmissionPublisher<>();
publisher.subscribe(item -> System.out.println("do something in the onNext"),
        e -> System.out.println("do something in the onError"),
        () -> System.out.println("Do something in the onComplete"));
```

I guess this is not possible and I´m not missing nothing here right?

Comment: Would be good if you could link to the library you are using for the current example that you shared.

Comment: I guess you mean the example where I'm using the lambdas. Is Rxjava https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: Nothing prevents you to write a Subscriber implementation that delegates to three different objects implementing interfaces that can be implemented as lambdas.

Comment: Of course I can, the question would be, why should I? At least having such a extension language as RxJava

Comment: Paul, are you saying that you would rather add a new dependency to your project and cause classpath hell, type explosion et cetera, versus writing a few lines of code somewhere?

Generally speaking, look at the API and documentation of a project like RxJava. It's madness and the sheer size of it is bound to cause great confusion and a steep learning curve. The JDK has always tried to keep things simple and to the point. If the end user wants an extra operator or Lambda functionality which is implemented with a few lines of code then let him write that code. That's our profession, after all.

Comment: Plus, reading source code I'd rather real quick jump into a util method and understand fully the project I am looking at versus having to study yet another library. I would use the JDK provided constructs first and foremost and only switch to a library if and when my need for "extra functionality" is more than trivial and equally fulfilled by a well-documented third party library.

Comment: Well is just a question of pick up a “better” (depends of your taste)implementation, of Reactive stream in Java. It’s not about to use Flow together with Observable of RxJava. You should just pick up one flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I still dont get it why this mechanism it´s needed

The subscription enables communication from subscriber to publisher. The `request` method allows the subscriber to apply [backpressure](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Back-Pressure), informing upstream components that it is overloaded and "needs a break". In order to do that, the subscriber needs to hold on to an instance of the subscription and needs to occasionally call `request` to get more items.

### No pressure `Subscriber`

If you have a use case, where you don't need to apply backpressure and would like to benefit from the reduced complexity, you could implement a `LaidBackSubscriber`, which:

- implements `onSubscribe` by storing the subscription and immediately calling `request` on it
- implements `onNext` by executing a lambda given during construction and then calling `subscription.request(1)`
- implements `onError` and `onComplete` by  executing a lambda given during construction

That should get you what you wanted.

### General advice

The Java 9 Flow API [was created](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266#Description) as an integration point for existing async libraries, not as an invitation to implement reactive components in an ad-hoc fashion. It's great to experiment with, but if you really want to create a reactive system, the existing libraries are likely well-suited.

Comment: Yes I understand that but in RxJava the back pressure is achieve by some operators as buffer or window. This implementation is really bad I think

Comment: The Java 9 Flow API [was created](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266#Description) as an integration point for existing async libraries and as such it focused on interoperability. How would RxJava's "buffer or window" implement backpressure via the Flow API if it contained no such concept.

Comment: Well it's just that I was expected with this API, at least the same capabilities as another reactives API such as RxJava, Akka stream or Spring reactor.

Comment: Is LaidBackSubscriber part of the Flow API? I was doing some experiments. After what I see I will keep RxJava in my stack for sure.

Comment: No, I just made that up. ;) "After what I see I will keep RxJava in my stack for sure" That's exactly the right thing to do! The Flow API is not meant as a replacement for existing reactive libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 9 Flow API is a barebone set of 4 interfaces and 1 bridge class from non-reactive to reactive world. No operators, no convenience lambda versions, nothing else.

In theory, it was introduced to allow the JDK itself to build up internal components based on the reactive principles but there no reassuring signs this is happening.

Thus, the users are responsible to build up components on this API which is difficult, tedious and error-prone. You are better off waiting for the mainstream libraries to release compatible versions or just stick to the more available Reactive-Streams.Org-based libraries such as RxJava 2 and Reactor 3.

If you are still interested in building on top of the Flow API by hand, you can have a look at my research/prototype library [Reactive4JavaFlow](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow#reactive4javaflow), which has the  desired [lambda](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/reactive4javaflow/Folyam.java#L75) overload [implemented](https://github.com/akarnokd/Reactive4JavaFlow/blob/master/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/reactive4javaflow/impl/consumers/LambdaConsumer.java).

Comment: You write: "In theory, it was introduced to allow the JDK itself to build up internal components based on the reactive principles but there no reassuring signs this is happening." This is patently wrong. [JEP 266](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266#Description) states: "These interfaces [...] support interoperability across a number of async systems running on JVMs. [...] There are no plans to provide network- or I/O-based java.util.concurrent components for distributed messaging, but it is possible that future JDK releases will include such APIs in other packages."

Comment: That role was already fulfilled by the reactivestreams.org version released in 2015 which is Java 6+ compatible and as such is more widely available. Including it in the JDK just for providing a rally point has little to no benefit unless the JDK itself is to use it, for example, providing a reactive JDBC API. Since the JDK doesn't tend to use 3rd party APIs, enabling such reactive API required the inclusion of the RS interfaces in the standard library. I saw signs that Oracle may not follow up on this angle and instead do something else...

Comment: "Including it in the JDK just for providing a rally point has little to no benefit" That might be true and you can of course disagree with the decision to include them in the JDK. But your statement that "it was introduced to allow the JDK itself to build up internal components based on the reactive principles" seems unlikely given that it directly contradicts public statements. If you have sources to back that up, please share.

Comment: The proof is in your own quote: "but it is possible that future JDK releases will include such APIs in other packages".

Comment: That's a gross misrepresentation. You say "It was introduced for X" but the JEP says "It was introduced for Y. There are no plans for X but it is possible in the future".

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, I wrote "allow the JDK" and the JEP says "possible in the future". InvokeDynamic allows the JDK to implement lambdas but Java 7 didn't include lambdas; only the next version did. I didn't write "allow (among other things) the JDK" because I don't find the argument for being an interoperation point in a different package strong enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155660/discussion-between-nicolai-and-akarnokd).